# How to change flutter app display name at runtime

Tags: android, ios, flutter

How do I change flutter app name at runtime, I have seen [this flutter plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dynamic_icon) which changes app's icon at runtime. I would like to know if there is a way to do this for the app name as well, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your app name is a variable which is accessed to be displayed, you can change it using setState like so

```
randomMethod() {
setState(() {
  myAppNameVariable = myNewNameString;
  //Do the same for the icon
  });
}
```

setState will reload the entire structure of the app while keeping variables and currenSstate of the components, so the name displayed will be different.

Comment: I'm talking about the launcher name